# Connecting to MariaDB server: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11

Tags: linux, mariadb, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an AWS hosted (RDS) MariaDB database (engine version 10.6.14).
The database is hosted on a private subnet but it's accessible through a bastion host. I use an SSH tunnel to bind the MariaDB server to my localhost.

I have successfully connected, queried and interacted with the database on a MacOS machine using DBeaver or a python script.

But I also need to connect to that instance through my Linux machine (Ubuntu 22). I can establish an SSH tunnel successfully but when I try to connect to the database I get the following error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11

That's whether I use:

- the command line `mysql -u <my_user> -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --password=<mypw>`
- the exact same python script I used on my MacOS machine

The DBeaver client returns the following error:

> unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)

Note:
`mysql --version` returns

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

my ssh tunnel set up command:

`ssh -i <my_pem_key_path.pem> -L 3306:<aws_host_url>:3306 <bastion_user>@<bastion_host> -N -f`

### Things I have tried

- disabled my firewall completely
- increased the size of the MariaDB cluster from db.t3.small to db.t3.large
- triple checked I'm using the same credentials on both machine
- tried a different network
- replaced `127.0.0.1` with `localhost`
- and all sorts of session variables edits

In case it's useful `telnet localhost 3306` returns:

> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to 127.0.0.1.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> Connection closed by foreign host.

### Config files

my.cnf :

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf:

```
# Copyright (c) 2015, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms,
# as designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301  USA

#
# The MySQL  Client configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysql]
```

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf:

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
```

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf:

```
#
# This group is read by the client library
# Use it for options that affect all clients, but not the server
#

[client]
# Example of client certificate usage
#ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
#ssl-key  = /etc/mysql/client-key.pem
#
# Allow only TLS encrypted connections
#ssl-verify-server-cert = on

# This group is *never* read by mysql client library, though this
# /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf.d/client.cnf file is not read by Oracle MySQL
# client anyway.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# use it for MariaDB-only client options
[client-mariadb]
```

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysql-clients.cnf:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB command-line tools
# Use it for options that affect only one utility
#
[mysql]

[mysql_upgrade]

[mysqladmin]

[mysqlbinlog]

[mysqlcheck]

[mysqldump]

[mysqlimport]

[mysqlshow]

[mysqlslap]
```

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/60-galera.cnf

```
#
# * Galera-related settings
#
# See the examples of server wsrep.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql
# and read more at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster/

[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on                 = ON
#wsrep_cluster_name       = "MariaDB Galera Cluster"
#wsrep_cluster_address    = gcomm://
#binlog_format            = row
#default_storage_engine   = InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0

# Optional settings
#wsrep_slave_threads = 1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

### sever error log

```
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.14-MariaDB-log source revision as process 460
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] RocksDB: 2 column families found
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] RocksDB: Column Families at start:
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] cf=default
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] write_buffer_size=67108864
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] target_file_size_base=67108864
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] cf=__system__
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] write_buffer_size=67108864
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] target_file_size_base=67108864
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] RocksDB: Table_store: loaded DDL data for 0 tables
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] RocksDB: global statistics using get_sched_indexer_t indexer
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] MyRocks storage engine plugin has been successfully initialized.
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1073741824, chunk size = 134217728
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.14 started; log sequence number 742767426; transaction id 38302
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ib_buffer_pool
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-09-30 8:30:14 0 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.14-MariaDB-log' socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' port: 3306 managed by https://aws.amazon.com/rds/
2023-09-30 8:30:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230930 8:30:15
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

Comment: pplease add all other cnf files as well

Comment: i think you have an encrypted connection which reaches the mysql server

Comment: thanks for helping out @nbk. Added all my .cnf files

Comment: nothing soecial about that, but can you also add the mysql error log, it seems to,me that the mysql sever is not running

Comment: The error log looks clean to me (see edit). The server is running according to the aws console and my macos machine can query it.

Comment: the ssh tunnel doesn't pass the packages to the mariadb server, may be you should ask this question with serverfault

Comment: I'll try thanks !